# How can I make gcc generate a warning if I compare doubles?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings

I want to catch equality comparisons of doubles in my code and get warnings for them. Is there a GCC warning that will do this?

It's not something that can be easily grepped for in the source code.

Comment: for equality comparisons, `-Wfloat-equal`

Comment: Damn, I should have put is as an answer!

Comment: clang has `-Weverything` that you can use to enable literally all warnings clang has. Warnings indicate the specific flag that enables them, so you can use that to find flags. I imagine gcc has something similar so you don't just have to rely on documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC 4.7.0 has:

```
gcc --help=warnings
```

and it produces, amongst many others:

```
-Wfloat-equal               Warn if testing floating point numbers for equality
```

(GCC 4.1.2 does not support the extended help; it 'just' has `--help`.  It does have the warning option, though.)

Answer (score 5):

A quick `man gcc` reveals this as a likely candidate

```
    -Wfloat-equal
```